# iPod's Rx/Tx doesn't work well with iOS6.0, but it works fine with iOS4.x & iOS5.x

Tags: ios6, ipod, reboot, rxtx

My JailBroke iPod4's Rx/Tx works fine on iOS4.x and iOS5.x version, but something is different with iOS6.x

It works when iPod4(iOS6.0) is wake up, but if iPod4 enter into deep sleep and wake up again, Rx/Tx doesn't work anymore, only respring or reboot iPod4 can make it work again, it seems Rx/Tx is be turned off.

why, anyone can help?